# How to remove an specific <li> with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out, how am i able to delete a specific `<li>` with pure javascript ?
My purpose is: each `<li>` does have a "remove" button and if we click on that button, it will remove that `<li>`.

```
function remove(r){
    **REMOVE**
}

function add(){
    var ul = document.getElementById("ul");
    var li = document.createElement("li");

    if(document.getElementById("nameS").value && document.getElementById("mailS").value){
        var nameS = document.createElement("i");
        nameS.innerHTML = document.getElementById("nameS").value;
        nameS.innerHTML += ": ";

        var mailS = document.createElement("font");
        mailS.setAttribute("color","#000080");
        mailS.innerHTML = document.getElementById("mailS").value;
        mailS.innerHTML += " - ";

        if(document.getElementById("webpageS").value){
            mailS.innerHTML += "<a href="+document.getElementById("webpageS").value+">"+document.getElementById("webpageS").value+"</a>";
        }

        var element = document.createElement("input");
        element.setAttribute("type","button");
        element.setAttribute("value","Remover");
        //element.setAttribute("onclick",remove());
        element.addEventListener('click',function(){
               li.remove();
        },false);


        li.appendChild(nameS);
        li.appendChild(mailS);
        li.appendChild(element);
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }


}
```

Comment: note that `element.setAttribute("onclick",remove());` will _call the function_, not bind it as an event handler.  also you should be using `element.addEventListener` for that.  but you seem to know the DOM API already; just go to the parent element (which is the `<li>`) and remove it from its parent.

Comment: Oh... That function exists on javascript ? Didnt know about that ! I will try to figure out ! 
I saw a bunch of different answers but none with the eventlistener ! That's why i did with the function remove :f

Comment: Seems it is working with your solution ! 
i will put my solution ! 
Can you check and see if it's right what i did please ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add your `remove` function using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) as suggested by @Eevee, the first argument passed to `remove` will be an `Event` object. (For a click event, it will be a [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) object.)

Every `Event` object has a property, `target`, which tells you where the element came from. So, you can simply [go up the tree of elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode) to get the `li`, and [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove) that:

```
function removeParent(evt) {
  evt.target.parentNode.remove();
}

element.addEventListener('click', removeParent, false);
```

---

Some other comments on your code:

- Please don't ever use `font` elements; likewise `i` elements. You should use `span` if you want to apply styles; if you want to *emphasise text*, use `em`.

Comment: But i dont understand one thing, if it delete my MouseEvent Object, why does it delete at the same time the <li> ?

Comment: "potentially reparsing"? Is like half-clicking a button?

Comment: Whats the difference between your code and eevee code ? It did the same remove, is it more harmful to use the eevee code ?

Comment: @Damiii first comment: `evt.target.parentNode.remove()` will remove the event's target's parent. So, the event is on the `input[type=button]`; that's `evt.target`. The `li` is the button's `parentNode`, and calling `remove()` removes the element.

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9 What I mean is that if you have an element `el`, then call `el.innerHTML = '<a href="example.net">Example</a>'`, *then* call `el.innerHTML += '<a "href=example.net/2/">Ex. 2</a>`, your browser *might* decode the first line at the first call, *then* decode *both* at the second call.

Comment: @Jeremy it won't. It's a pointer to an object. It would be less efficient to create another object first, then use that to set el.innerHTML. By a multiple of two. My point was though - if you are saying "might", you don't know. Don't confuse the OP with conjecture.

Comment: @Damiii second comment: do you mean @Chausser's answer? I think my code is a little more direct, given that it doesn't rely on setting the `id` attribute when creating the elements. But @Chausser's approach is fine too.

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9 I disagree with you on the technical details, but I don't feel that strongly about it, and I can't find any good references on this matter, so I'll remove that point from my answer.

Comment: @Jeremy you're right, it's not that important to be worried about. I actually find stuff that like really interesting and important though - so more my issue than anything else.

Comment: @Jeremy - I must retract - you are right... http://jsperf.com/string-concats-for-rob

Answer (score 1):

What i would do would be to add a unique id to each of the li's that you can later reference to remove it:

```
var curId = 0;
function add(){
....

var li = document.createElement("li");
li.setAttribute(id,curId)

...

curId++;
}
```

Then in your button pass that id

```
element.setAttribute("onclick",remove(curId));
```

Then for your remove function it is simply:

```
function remove(ele){
    ducument.getElementById(ele).remove();
}
```

Comment: doesnt the function must be like :
function remove(ele){
    ducument.getElementById(ele).remove();
}
?

Comment: this is completely unnecessary; you can already find the element by traversing upwards from the button, and even if you couldn't, a closure would be more appropriate than giving elements ids counting from zero.